# C++ Форматирование текста

Tags: c++

Дается абзац текста, состоящий из ряда слов, отделенных друг от друга пробелами и/или символами новой строки (символы табуляции не применяются). Слово может содержать знаки пунктуации. Текст завершается специальным словом "$$$", которое будет единственным на последней строке.

Например, в тексте

```
The quick brown-fox jump$
over, the --- lazy
dog.
$$$
```

словами являются `"The", "quick", "brown-fox", "jump$", "over,", "the", "---", "lazy", "dog.".`

Последнее слово `"$$$"` рассматривать не нужно.

Вашей программе будет также дано целое число, указывающее ширину окна w. Вы должны вывести слова с минимальным количеством пробелов между ними так, чтобы:

1. количество символов в каждой строке не превышало w (за исключением символа новой строки).
2. между двумя словами на одной строке должен быть хотя бы один пробел.
3. крайний левый символ строки не должен быть пустым
4. крайний правый символ строки не должен быть пустым за исключением, может быть, последней строки
5. пробелы должны быть распределены по возможности равномерно между всеми словами строки. Если этого нельзя сделать точно, то большая порция пробелов должна располагаться ближе к правому краю строки.

При ширине вывода 21, вышеупомянутый текст отобразился бы следующим образом:

```
123456789012345678901
The  quick  brown-fox
jump$ over,  the  ---
lazy dog.
```

**Описание ввода:**

Первая строка входного файла содержит только ширину окна w. Следующие строки содержат текст абзаца. Последняя строка содержит единственное слово "$$$".

Гарантируется что:

- слово "$$$" не встречается внутри текста абзаца
- суммарная длина двух любых, подряд идущих слов, разделенных одним пробелом, не превышает w
- длина одного слова не превышает 50 символов
- количество слов в абзаце не превышает 5000
- ширина окна не превышает 100.

**Описание вывода:**

Выходной файл должен состоять из слов текста абзаца.
Не должно быть никаких пробелов в начале и конце файла.
Выходной файл д.б. в формате win1251.

Программа текст форматирует, но при проверке скрытых тестов, выдает ошибку. Какую ошибку выдает и что за тесты, не известно. Возможно я где-то не правильно понял задание или в самой программе есть хитрая ошибка.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. 2 недели мучаюсь, никак не могу понять в чем скрытый подвох.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



string inputSpace(string input, int size)

{

string rez = "", buf = input, tep = "";

int spaceNeed = size - input.length();
int lineLengyh;

bool flagg;

if (spaceNeed == 0) {
    flagg = false;
    rez = input;
}
else {
    flagg = true;
}

while (flagg)
{
    for (int i = buf.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        rez = buf[i] + rez;
        if (buf[i] == ' ' && buf[i - 1] != ' ' && spaceNeed > 0) {
            rez = ' ' + rez;
            spaceNeed--;
        }
        lineLengyh = rez.length();
    }

    if (spaceNeed == 0) {
        flagg = false;
    }
    else {
        buf = rez;
        rez = "";
    }
}

return rez;
}



int main()

{
ifstream innFile("input.txt");
ofstream outFile("output.txt");

string line;
stringstream ss;
vector<string> vec;

int maxLineSize;


innFile>>maxLineSize;

if (innFile.is_open()) {
    while (innFile.good()) {
        getline(innFile, line);

        ss << line << " ";
    }
}

line.empty();

while(ss>> line)
{

    vec.push_back(line);
}
vec.pop_back();

int lineSize;
line.empty();

for(size_t i = 0; i <= vec.size(); i++)
{
    line.clear();
    lineSize = 0;
    while(lineSize < maxLineSize)
    {
        lineSize += (int)vec[i].length();

        if(lineSize > maxLineSize) {
            i--;
            break;
        }

        if (i >= vec.size()){
            break;
        }

        line += vec[i];
        lineSize++;

        if(lineSize >= maxLineSize)
            break;

        line.push_back(' ');
        i++;
    }


    if (line[line.length() - 1] == ' ') {
        line.erase( line.end() - 1 );
    }

    if (i == vec.size()) {

        outFile << line << endl;
    } else {
        outFile << inputSpace(line, maxLineSize) << endl;
    }

}

innFile.close();
outFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что не так с приведенным кодом?

Comment: прохожу тестирование, надо отправить файл на сервер, где его подвергают секретным тестам, и после получаю результат, так вот данный код не прокатывает, пишет ошибка

Comment: ошибка в ответе? ошибка при компиляции? ошибка в рантайме?

Comment: ошибка в ответе, но посмотреть не дает.

Comment: Какие сценарии покрыли тестами (своими)?

Answer (score 3):

нашел ошибку:
XCode не ругался на ошибку, а вот Visual Studio  ругалась: vector subscript out of range, мол вектор выходит за рамки. Пришлось переделать.

```
while(lineSize < maxLineSize)
{
    lineSize += (int)vec[i].length();

    if(lineSize > maxLineSize) {
        i--;
        break;
    }

    if (i >= vec.size()){
        break;
    }

    line += vec[i];
    lineSize++;

    if(lineSize >= maxLineSize)
        break;

    line.push_back(' ');
    i++;
}
```

**в общем получилось вот так:**

```
while (lineSize < maxLineSize)
    {
-------------------------------------------
        if (i >= vec.size()) {
            break;
        }
-------------------------------------------
        lineSize += (int)vec[i].length();

        if (lineSize > maxLineSize) {
            i--;
            break;
        }

        line += vec[i];
        lineSize++;

        if (lineSize >= maxLineSize)
            break;

        line.push_back(' ');
        i++;
    }
```

перенес в начало и все заработало